# Which scripture mentions Lord Parshurama was born on Akshaya Tritiya?

Tags: scripture, avatars, festivals, parashurama, tithi

The [Drikpanchang](https://www.drikpanchang.com/dashavatara/parashurama/parashurama-jayanti-date-time.html) says that **Parshuram Jayanti** falls on Shukla Paksha Tritiya in the month of Vaishakha also known as **Akshay Tritiya**.

> It is believed that Parashurama was born during Pradosh Kala and hence the day when Tritiya prevails during Pradosh Kala is considered for Parashurama Jayanti celebrations.

**I want to know which scripture (if any) mentions that the two occasions fall on the same day.**

Answer (score 4):

[Uttarakalamrita](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uttara_Kalamrita) mentions that Lord Parshurama was born on Akshaya Tritiya.

> The auspicious day known as Tretadi or beginning of the Treta Yuga, or
> **when the birth of Parasurama is celebrated** is the 3rd lunar day in
> the month of Vaisakha (April-May)-Akshaya Tritiya.
>
> [[39, Kanda 2, UTTARAKALAMRITA (OF KALIDASA)]](https://www.indiadivine.org/content/files/file/88-uttarakalamrita-in-sanskrit-with-english-translations-pdf/)