# Do we have any preaching or works of Lord Parashurama?

Tags: parashurama

Today is [Parashurama](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parashurama) [Jayanti](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/26868/277). He is one of the principle       Avatara of Vishnu according to Srimad Bhagavata Purana. We find his stories/roles in Ramayana as well as in Mahabharata. He was born to a Brahmin Rishi. So, a thought came in my mind if we have any preaching of Parashurama.

Has he written any works like Sutra, a Smriti or composition of Stotras? In other words, do we have any works attributed to Parashurama? Or Is his preaching found in sections of Puranas?

Comment: As today is parashurama Jayanti, His contribution where of his followers greatest of them is Bhisma who had given "Vishnusharanama" for the deliverance of the world. Bhisma studied for more than 50 years under Parashurama Avatara and also studied futher for 250 years.. so total 300 odd years passed under parashurama.. Jaisri prasaruama..

Comment: I don't know whether this qualifies as a preaching but the Meru Tantra advises the worship of Parashurama for protection against non-Hindus.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

"Parshurama Kalpa Sutras" is one of his great works. Bhagwan Parshurama was devotee of Shiva.He has made a great contribution to srIvidhyA upAsana and Tantra by writing Parshurama Kalpa Suras which is compilation of five AmnAyas(PurvamnAya, dakshinAmnAya, pashchimAmnaya,uttarAmnAya and urdhvAmnAya. These 5 AmnAyas are told by Shiva to Devi Shakti when questioned from his 5 sri mukhas SadyojAta, vAmadeva, Aghora, tatpurusha and Ishana respectively.

**IMPORTANT:** Like Vedas are shAstras for Vedika, similarly PKS is shAstras for Tantrika.

Reference: [Page No. 3, ParshuramKalpaSutram by Dr. Param Hans Mishra](https://www.exoticindiaart.com/book/details/parashuram-kalpa-sutra-NZF962/)

Comment: This is very interesting to know. Usually Kalpa Sutras refer to one of the Vedanga. I don't know much about Tantra.

Comment: Interesting! Could you share a link to details on that Vedanga? @Paṇḍyā

Comment: Sure! Refer [this](https://dharmawiki.org/index.php/Shad_Vedangas_(%E0%A4%B7%E0%A4%A1%E0%A5%8D%E0%A4%B5%E0%A5%87%E0%A4%A6%E0%A4%BE%E0%A4%99%E0%A5%8D%E0%A4%97%E0%A4%BE%E0%A4%A8%E0%A4%BF)) for Vedanga and [this](https://dharmawiki.org/index.php/Kalpa_Vedanga_(%E0%A4%95%E0%A4%B2%E0%A5%8D%E0%A4%AA%E0%A4%B5%E0%A5%87%E0%A4%A6%E0%A4%BE%E0%A4%99%E0%A5%8D%E0%A4%97%E0%A4%AE%E0%A5%8D)) for Kalpa

Comment: Thank you @Paṇḍyā :-)