# Oldest scripture that mentions Lord Parashurama?

Tags: puranas, parashurama, itihasa

Which scripture (Itihasa, Purana, etc.) mentions Lord Parashurama for the first time?

Comment: You may want to read this: https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/38570/647  :)

Comment: see this https://books.google.com/books?id=fETebHcHKogC

Comment: How do we define oldest ? If not mistaken brihadaranyaka upanishad says scriptures including vedas, smritis, puranas etc  are revealed at the same time at the beginning of each kalpa.

Answer (score 4):

Seer of [Rig Veda X.110](https://books.google.com/books?id=fgzVAwAAQBAJ&lpg=PP1&pg=PA1576#v=onepage&q&f=false) is Parashurama himself.

> X.110
>
> Deity: Āprī
>
> Seer: Jamadagni Bhārgava or Rāma Jāmadagnya
>
> 11 verses: triṣṭubh