# Is Parashuram Janmotsav celebrated today?

Tags: parashurama

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8spf_ttHMhY

Parashuran Janmotsav special is the title of the video.

Is Parashuram Janmotsav celebrated today like Ram Navami, Gokulasjtami etc.?

EDIT: not a duplicate of

[Which scripture mentions Lord Parshurama was born on Akshaya Tritiya?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/26868/which-scripture-mentions-lord-parshurama-was-born-on-akshaya-tritiya)

Akshaya Tritiya is considered auspicious for buying new jewelry - my question is whether it is celebrated as Parashurama Jayanti specifically referring to him, similar to Ram Navami, Gokulashtami etc.?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Which scripture mentions Lord Parshurama was born on Akshaya Tritiya?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/26868/which-scripture-mentions-lord-parshurama-was-born-on-akshaya-tritiya)

Comment: Please read the answer, it clearly says that.